# Setting listview backcolor in Access 2007, VBA

Tags: listview, vba, ms-access-2007

I know there are a lot of discussions regarding this question out there. Unfortunately the most for VB.net.
I am using Access 2007 and the ActiveX ListView control. So far it's working fine. Except setting the back ground color for an subitem or a column is not working.

[EDIT]
To be more specific. In VB the following should work:
`editListView1.Items(i).UseItemStyleForSubItems = false`
`editListView1.Items(i).SubItems(8).BackColor = Color.LightGray`

Unfortunately in VBA the "items" property is not available. If i use
`editListView1.ListItems(i).UseItemStyleForSubItems`, I get an error.

on the other hand changing the fore color works without any problem:
`objListView.ListItems.Item(intRowCount).ListSubItems.Item(intColCount).ForeColor = vbRed`

I really would appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: "Not working" is never a good description of a problem. This http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=231157 should work in VBA with little or no change.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using the *Microsoft Listview Control* from `mscomctl/comctl32.ocx` then you cannot set the background colour of an individual row or sub-item, you can only set the foreground colour .

The only way around that is to go through the tedious steps of [custom drawing](http://btmtz.mvps.org/listview/) it.